# Ionic - Weird transparent statusbar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, statusbar

I am currently developing an app with ionic 3 and I experience one problem from the beginning.
The Statusbar on the startpage (ONLY on the startpage) looks transparent. Here‘s a screenshot:

[image: weird statusbar]

But all the other pages look how they should look:

[image: normal statusbar]

Why is that so and what can I do to get rid of this issue?

HTML of the startpage:

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="head">
    <div class="balance">
      301 &euro;
    </div>
    <div class="balancetext">
      CURRENT BALANCE
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <button class="addbutton" (click)="onNewIncome()">
        <img src="./assets/imgs/plus.png"> INCOME
      </button>
      <div class="split"></div>
      <button class="exbutton">
        <img src="./assets/imgs/minus.png"> EXPENSE
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

and necessary SCSS:

```
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f5f8fa;
  }
  .head{
    background-image: url('../assets/imgs/pattern_1.png');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 15em;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  }
```

Comment: can you add the html for the start page? you need to provide [mcve]

Comment: @SurajRao added the code

Comment: hmm.. nothing from the code.. is it iphoneX (ios11)?

Comment: @SurajRao Nope. Took the screenshot on an iPhone 8+, but I'm experiencing this problem on every iOS device in simulator (not tested on android yet) but it is iOS 11

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007306/status-bar-on-ios-background-color